# Export libvirt VM to vmx (howto generate virt-image)

Tags: vmware, export, kvm-switch, libvirt

To convert from vmware to libvirt, I'd do:

```
virt-convert myvm.vmx -o virt-image IMAGE.XML
virt-image IMAGE.XML
```

but how do I create an image descriptor from a libvirt domain to be able to reverse the export back to vmware?

Answer (score 1):

### libvirt solution:

***Converting from domain XML config to VMware VMX config.***
The virsh domxml-to-native provides a way to convert a domain XML config into a VMware VMX config.
  This is a new tool without much documentation yet, but no options should really be needed.
https://libvirt.org/drvesx.html

This was an older solution:
Under ***Convert Domain XML Format Configuration File to libvirt “image” XML Configuration File (virt-image).***   http://virtuallyhyper.com/2013/06/migrate-from-libvirt-kvm-to-virtualbox/